# How do I use VBA to see if a worksheet contains any precedents?

Tags: excel, vba

I am putting together a macro to identify wasted space in a workbook.  One of the things I want to identify are tabs that are not referenced anywhere else in the workbook.

I've tried a dependents.count loop, as well as the Find seen in my code.  Not tied to any one way, just needs to be done in VBA.

```
Sub Test3()

Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim r As Range


a = 1
i = 1
j = Application.Sheets.Count
j = j + 1

Do While i < j
a = a + 1
With Worksheets(i).UsedRange
Set r = .Find(Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)


If Not r Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "Yes"
Else: Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "No"
End If

End With
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Looking for worksheets that are referenced in the tab to have a "Yes" in column D of the Summary tab.  Ones that are not referenced should have a "No".

Comment: So what's the problem with your code?

Comment: It's not properly recognizing cells that contain the sheet names in the formulas.  I get "No" for sheets that are referenced in other sheets and "Yes" for sheets that are not.

Comment: @BradLee This would not work only if the Sheet Summary is the first sheet of your workbook

Comment: `Option Explicit`. Indenting. Learn how to do `For Each` or to use a `For... Next` loop. Understand your `If ... Then` statement and you will easily see why your logic is reversed.

Comment: @BradLee I just saw your issue was salved, may I ask you to accept [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57097656/11167163) So your issue will be set as solved?  Kindest regards Dorian

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give this a try, it might work

```
Sub Test3()

Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim r As Range


a = 1
i = 1
j = Application.Sheets.Count

If Sheets(1).Name = "Summary" Then
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "Yes"
Else: Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "No"
End If


Do While i < j
a = a + 1
With Worksheets(i).UsedRange
Set r = .Find(Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)


If Not r Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "Yes"
Else: Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "No"
End If

End With
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like it works if Summary is at the start.  Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally got to work.  Other answers may have been sufficient and I just wasn't applying them correctly.  Thanks to all who helped.

```
Sub Dependents()

Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim r As Range


a = 2
i = 1
j = Application.Sheets.Count
k = Application.Sheets.Count
k = k + 1


Do While i < j

a = 2

Do While a < k

With Worksheets(i).UsedRange
Set r = .Find(Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value <> "Yes" Then

If Not r Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "Yes"
Else: Worksheets("Summary").Cells(a, 4).Value = "No"
End If

End If

End With

a = a + 1

Loop

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```